# Pipeline-init can not create directory

Tags: linux, fedora, postgresql, cluster

First of all, the `pipeline-init` command has the same function as the postgres `initdb`. The difference is that pipeline is a postgres fork.

```
dbastos@localhost ~/traderbot> pipeline-init -D /pipeline
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "dbastos".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "pt_BR.UTF-8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "portuguese".

Data page checksums are disabled.

creating directory /pipeline ... pipeline-init: could not create directory "/pipeline": Permission denied


dbastos@localhost ~/traderbot> ls -la
total 24
drwxrwxr-x.  4 dbastos dbastos 4096 jan 20 16:53 ./
drwx------. 26 dbastos dbastos 4096 jan 20 16:35 ../
drwxrwxr-x.  2 dbastos dbastos 4096 jan 20 08:29 config/
-rw-rw-r--.  1 dbastos dbastos  234 jan 20 08:36 index.js
drwxrwxr-x. 29 dbastos dbastos 4096 jan 20 08:19 node_modules/
-rw-rw-r--.  1 dbastos dbastos  205 jan 20 08:09 package.json
```

This error is common in `initdb`, but I have not found any of the solutions to resolve it in `pipelinedb`.
And one more information my OS is Fedora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are running this as non-root (as user `dbastos`), and trying to create a top-level directory `/pipeline`. That's why you are getting a permissions-denied error. You should use a directory that you have write-access to. You might want `~/pipeline` (which is another way of writing `/home/dbastos/pipeline`).